# Ideas for a method to obtain a cell which has been randomly generated in another class

Tags: java

this is my first question in stackoverflow :)

I need help with the method obtenerUltimaCelda (spanish name)

```
public Celda obtenerUltimaCelda() {
    return //¿?
}
```

I had this other method in the class Generador that obtains a random cell of a board

```
public static Celda obtenerCeldaAleatoria(Tablero tablero) {

    int x, y;

    do {
        x = (int) (Math.random() * tablero.obtenerNumeroFilas());
        y = (int) (Math.random() * tablero.obtenerNumeroColumnas());
    } while (!tablero.obtenerCelda(x, y).estaVacia());

    return tablero.obtenerCelda(x, y);
}
```

My method obtenerUltimaCelda has to return the same cell that obtenerCeldaAleatoria obtains.
For example if obtenerCeldaAleatoria returns the position of 1,3 obtenerUltimaCelda has to return the same position.

Any ideas?

Comment: Store the copies of the values obtained in a global variable? :P

Comment: That works, incredibly I didn't realized of that posibility xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to need more details for us to fully understand, but it sounds as if to me that your class needs a Celda variable, perhaps called ultimaCelda, and you should fill that variable with the Celda returned whenever obtenerCeldaAleatoria is called. That way later if you need the last Celda, simply call your getter method, obtenerUltimaCelda, to retrieve the Celda held in the field. As an aside, I am a little confused by the fact that your posted code shows one method as being static and the other being non-static. Best would be if all methods and fields involved in this were not static.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return the instance of Celda with same x and y, you can try this-

```
public class Celda{

private int x;

private int y;

Celda(int inputX, int inputY)
{
  x = inputX;
  y = inputY;
}

}

public Celda obtenerUltimaCelda(int x, int y) {
    return new Celda(x,y);
}
```